# Package Family Name changed with new code signing cert

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-runtime, sideloading

Previously we have one code signing cert, every thing working fine. Recently cert expired so we taken new cert from Comodo and released new build with that cert.

So here is the problem: Package Family Name Changed with that new cert, so I am not able to upgrade old installed apps with this new build packaged with new cert.

Need solution for this to maintain Package Family Name as constant or for new cert's also we need to provide upgrade for older apps.

How can we achieve this?

Error msg while upgrading package from PowerShell:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed
updates, dependency or conflict validation.
Windows cannot install package df70dbc9-455c-4c32-b052-7ac2943630b7_1.0.193.1_x64__qbsrcgy0j364g
because a different package df70dbc9-455c-4c32-b052-7ac2943630b7_1.0.0.191_x64__hs446qhh7vdt4
with the same name is already installed. Remove package
df70dbc9-455c-4c32-b052-7ac2943630b7_1.0.0.191_x64__hs446qhh7vdt4 before
installing.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
b0deec37-ac10-0001-81fd-deb010acd101 in the Event Log or use the command line
Get-AppxLog -ActivityID b0deec37-ac10-0001-81fd-deb010acd101
At C:\Users\\Desktop\\myappName_1.0.193.1_x64_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1:388 char:13
+             Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -DependencyPath ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\myuser....193.1_x64.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
Error: Could not install the app.
```

Comment: Exception says it all. Uninstall the old package before installing a new one with the same name, no?

Comment: our intention has to upgrade app,without loosing saved data

Answer (score 8):

The Package Family Name (PFN) suffix (in your case `hs446qhh7vdt4`) is a hash of the certificate's *subject* (AKA *subject name*):

```
certutil -dump foo.pfx
Enter PFX password:
================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Issuer: CN=Microsoft, O=Contoso, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
 NotBefore: 11/1/2016 12:00 AM
 NotAfter: 11/1/2017 12:00 AM
Subject: CN=Microsoft, O=Contoso, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US <== THIS IS HASHED
```

If you make sure the new cert you generate has the same subject, you'll get the same PFN. Note that you might not be able to generate store certs from within Visual Studio (at the time of writing, it can't parse complex subjects like the one above with multiple 'parts' like `CN=X`, `O=Y`). In that case you'll have to create your own, but it must comply with the [store validations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230260%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Luckily, there's a simple command that generates the exact certificate you need. Open a Visual Studio developer prompt and run (one line):

```
makecert -sv foo.pvk -n "CN=Contoso, O=Contoso, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" 
    foo.cer -b 11/01/2016 -e 11/01/2017 -r -cy end -a sha256 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3
```

Make sure to replace the validity dates (no more than a year apart!) as well as the subject (taken from your previous cert using `certutil -dump`). The names of the output cert (`cer`) and private key (`pvk`) are meaningless. That command  will generate `foo.pvk` and `foo.cer`, which you will then be able to combine to a pfx like so:

```
PVK2PFX -pvk foo.pvk -spc foo.cer -pfx foo.pfx
```

**Another option for advanced generation**

In case you have more advanced cert requirements, you should be able to use [`certreq`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456(v=ws.11).aspx) (haven't tested it though). Create a file named `cert.inf` with the following contents:

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"

[Strings]
szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE = "2.5.29.37"
szOID_CODE_SIGNING = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3"
szOID_BASIC_CONSTRAINTS2 = "2.5.29.19"

[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=Contoso, O=Contoso, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
Exportable = true
HashAlgorithm = Sha256
KeyLength = 2048
RequestType = Cert
ValidityPeriod = "Years"
ValidityPeriodUnits = "1"

[Extensions]
%szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE% = "{text}%szOID_CODE_SIGNING%"
%szOID_BASIC_CONSTRAINTS2% = "{text}"
```

Replace the subject and validity period, and adjust any advanced settings you need per the docs (or more likely found on the web). Then do the following:

1. `certreq -new cert.inf cert.cer`
2. Double-click the resulting `cert.cer` and install it to the *Trusted Root Certificate Authorities* store (either user or machine).
3. `certreq -accept -user cert.cer` OR `certreq -accept -machine cert.cer` (depending on the store you picked in the previous step).
4. Go to the *Personal* store in the cert manager (user or machine scope, depending on what you picked above) and find the cert you just installed. Double-click it and copy the serial number from the details tab (I encountered some voodoo here where the cert would only show up after a long time, or after I installed a different cert (with a different subject name).
5. `certutil -exportpfx -p "YOUR_PFX_PASS" my SERIAL_NUMBER foo.pfx` (replace the password and the serial number with their actual values)

You should now have a valid store pfx.

**Yet another option for even more advanced generation**

Use [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Pretty sure it can do all the above and more, but I haven't tried it personally so you'll have to figure it out - and hopefully share here once you do!

Comment: Perfect! When Visual Studio found my expired certificate, it created a new one with different publisher name. This created the same update issue